# Mixing Powermock with Weld?

Tags: java, cdi, mockito, powermock, weld

We have a project that uses

- Weld-SE for dependency injection
- static native methods to call a native library

When writing unit tests, in order to test managed beans that interact with the native library, we'd like to mock the class on which they're defined. However, [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) (specifically, the annotation [`@PrepareForTest`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.4/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html)) seems to mess with Weld's initialization. For example, if I have the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticNativeAPI.class)
public class Test {
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    WeldContainer wc = new Weld().initialize();
  }
}
```

then Weld will fail to initialize with the following error:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001423 Cannot
>   enable the same alternative bean class
>   [com.mycompany.AltBean in
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/Me/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/project/version-SNAPSHOT/project-version-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml@8,
>   com.mycompany.AltBean in
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/Me/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/project/version-SNAPSHOT/project-version-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml@8]
>   in beans.xml

```
at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled.createMetadataMap(Enabled.java:123)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled.<init>(Enabled.java:94)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled.of(Enabled.java:79)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.<init>(BeanDeployment.java:114)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap$DeploymentVisitor.visit(WeldBootstrap.java:184)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap$DeploymentVisitor.visit(WeldBootstrap.java:153)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startContainer(WeldBootstrap.java:284)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.ForwardingBootstrap.startContainer(ForwardingBootstrap.java:42)
at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:129)
at com.mycompany.Test.setup(Test.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:43)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:234)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:188)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:166)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

In other words, it appears to be parsing `beans.xml` twice. Does anybody know how to get these two libraries to play nicely together?

Comment: Did you try to rely on CDI 1.1 implicit activation. If you don't provide a beans.xml, CDI is activated with the `annotated` bean-discovery mode. You should be sure to have all your bean annotated with a CDI Scope (@ApplicationScoped or @Dependent) and use Weld 2.x to be on CDI 1.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, for now we're stuck using Weld 1.9. I'll have to look into the possibility of upgrading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a [bug with the MockClassLoader](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=426).

I submitted a patch, so it will probably be fixed by version 1.5.5.